# Return unique numbers associated with each row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to get Excel to return unique numbers associated with each row.

I would like the cells in Column C to return how many classes were taught by teachers A, B and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with two additional helper columns, which can be hidden if you don't want to see them.

Cell C2 formula (drag down) combines Teacher and Class to make it easier to look up combos:

```
=A2&" "&B2
```

Cell D2 formula (drag down) counts occurences of each combo. Note that the lack of $ in the second "$C$2:C2," allows the formula to count up sequentially as it find matches.

```
=COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)
```

Then the final formula in E2 (drag down) counts up first occurrences of each combo for each teacher.

```
=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$8,$D$2:$D$8,1,$A$2:$A$8,A2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir Adelaide. This is really very helpful and I'm so grateful!!!! You've made my weekend so much easier! Gracias! Gracias!!!!!

Comment: No worries, glad to help. If your problem is solved, may I suggest that you accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 0):

cocatenate A and B columns

> `=CONCATENATE(A3,B3)`
>   it will look like this,special paste values only

```
    Teacher/Class
    AX
    AY
    AZ
    AZ
    BL
    BL
    BL
```

drag down the column,copy this column to a different column and paste values only,now select the column,and goto Data -> Remove duplicates,will give you this data.
                      Teacher/Class
                          AX
                          AY
                          AZ
                          BL
now apply formula,

```
=COUNTIF(E3:E6,"A*") will return 3
=COUNTIF(E3:E6,"B*") will return 1.
```